Use get_object_references to get all level dependencies of a object in snowflake
I have a view called cplx_vw1 in which there are again nested views and tables
my task is to break the level of cplx_wl1 till I found the refernced object type as table
so if the above contains two views and those two views contain another view and table
I have to get the below output



REFERENCED_OBJECT_NAME
REFERENCED_OBJECT_DOMAIN
Dependent View Object
REFERENCING_OBJECT_NAME
REFERENCING_OBJECT_DOMAIN
Level




EXAMPLE_SCHEMA.EXAMPLE_TABLE_1
TABLE

EXAMPLE_SCHEMA.EXAMPLE_VIEW_1
VIEW
1


EXAMPLE_SCHEMA.EXAMPLE_TABLE_2
TABLE

EXAMPLE_SCHEMA.EXAMPLE_VIEW_1
VIEW
1


EXAMPLE_SCHEMA.EXAMPLE_TABLE_3
TABLE

EXAMPLE_SCHEMA.EXAMPLE_VIEW_1
VIEW
1


EXAMPLE_SCHEMA.EXAMPLE_TABLE_4
TABLE

EXAMPLE_SCHEMA.EXAMPLE_VIEW_1
VIEW
1


ANOTHER_SCHEMA.ANOTHER_TABLE_1
TABLE

YET_ANOTHER_SCHEMA.YET_ANOTHER_VIEW_1
VIEW
1


ANOTHER_SCHEMA.ANOTHER_TABLE_2
TABLE

YET_ANOTHER_SCHEMA.YET_ANOTHER_VIEW_1
VIEW
1


ANOTHER_SCHEMA.ANOTHER_TABLE_3
TABLE

YET_ANOTHER_SCHEMA.YET_ANOTHER_VIEW_1
VIEW
1


YET_ANOTHER_SCHEMA.YET_ANOTHER_TABLE_1
TABLE

YET_ANOTHER_SCHEMA.YET_ANOTHER_VIEW_1
VIEW
1


YET_ANOTHER_SCHEMA.YET_ANOTHER_TABLE_2
TABLE

YET_ANOTHER_SCHEMA.YET_ANOTHER_VIEW_1
VIEW
1


ANOTHER_SCHEMA.ANOTHER_TABLE_4
TABLE

YET_ANOTHER_SCHEMA.YET_ANOTHER_VIEW_1
VIEW
1


EXAMPLE_SCHEMA.EXAMPLE_TABLE_5
TABLE

EXAMPLE_SCHEMA.EXAMPLE_VIEW_1
VIEW
1


EXAMPLE_SCHEMA.EXAMPLE_TABLE_6
TABLE
EXAMPLE_SCHEMA.EXAMPLE_DEPENDENT_VIEW
EXAMPLE_SCHEMA.EXAMPLE_VIEW_2
VIEW
2


ANOTHER_SCHEMA.ANOTHER_TABLE_5
TABLE

EXAMPLE_SCHEMA.EXAMPLE_VIEW_2
VIEW
2


ANOTHER_SCHEMA.ANOTHER_TABLE_6
TABLE
ANOTHER_SCHEMA.ANOTHER_DEPENDENT_VIEW
EXAMPLE_SCHEMA.EXAMPLE_VIEW_2
VIEW
2


EXAMPLE_SCHEMA.EXAMPLE_TABLE_7
TABLE

ANOTHER_SCHEMA.ANOTHER_DEPENDENT_VIEW
VIEW
2


EXAMPLE_SCHEMA.EXAMPLE_TABLE_8
TABLE

ANOTHER_SCHEMA.ANOTHER_DEPENDENT_VIEW
VIEW
2


EXAMPLE_SCHEMA.EXAMPLE_TABLE_9
TABLE

ANOTHER_SCHEMA.ANOTHER_DEPENDENT_VIEW
VIEW
2


ANOTHER_SCHEMA.ANOTHER_TABLE_7
TABLE

ANOTHER_SCHEMA.ANOTHER_DEPENDENT_VIEW
VIEW
2


ANOTHER_SCHEMA.ANOTHER_TABLE_8
TABLE

ANOTHER_SCHEMA.ANOTHER_DEPENDENT_VIEW
VIEW
2



I was doing this manually, but the I thouhgt to use the below query , but couldn't get to the above target
`
WITH cte AS (
SELECT * FROM TABLE(get_object_references(
    DATABASE_NAME=>'prod1',
    SCHEMA_NAME=>'PUBLIC',
    OBJECT_NAME=>'cplx_vw1'
)) AS ref
 ),
level1_cte AS (
SELECT
    REFERENCED_DATABASE_NAME,
    REFERENCED_SCHEMA_NAME,
    REFERENCED_OBJECT_NAME,
    REFERENCED_OBJECT_TYPE AS Level_1_Object_Type,
    REFERENCED_DATABASE_NAME || '.' || REFERENCED_SCHEMA_NAME || '.' || REFERENCED_OBJECT_NAME AS Level_1_Object_Name
FROM cte
   )
 SELECT * 
  FROM TABLE(GET_OBJECT_REFERENCES(
DATABASE_NAME=> (SELECT REFERENCED_DATABASE_NAME FROM level1_cte),
SCHEMA_NAME=> (SELECT REFERENCED_SCHEMA_NAME FROM level1_cte),
OBJECT_NAME=> (SELECT REFERENCED_OBJECT_NAME FROM level1_cte)
));

`
any help is appreciated.

Please not account_usage.get_object_dependencies can't be used due to access privilege

I would suggest trying the below, you can export to excel and seperate the first column then using text to columns option.
WITH RECURSIVE referenced_cte
(object_name_path, referenced_object_name, referenced_object_domain, referencing_object_domain, referencing_object_name, referenced_object_id, referencing_object_id)
    AS
      (
        SELECT referenced_object_name || '-->' || referencing_object_name as object_name_path,
               referenced_object_name, referenced_object_domain, referencing_object_domain, referencing_object_name, referenced_object_id, referencing_object_id
          FROM snowflake.account_usage.object_dependencies referencing

        UNION ALL

        SELECT object_name_path || '-->' || referencing.referencing_object_name,
              referencing.referenced_object_name, referencing.referenced_object_domain, referencing.referencing_object_domain, referencing.referencing_object_name,
              referencing.referenced_object_id, referencing.referencing_object_id
          FROM snowflake.account_usage.object_dependencies referencing JOIN referenced_cte
            ON referencing.referenced_object_id = referenced_cte.referencing_object_id
            AND referencing.referenced_object_domain = referenced_cte.referencing_object_domain
      )

  SELECT object_name_path, referenced_object_name, referenced_object_domain, referencing_object_name, referencing_object_domain
    FROM referenced_cte
;

